# Append non english chars to json file

Tags: php

I'm trying to append new item to json file which the fields value are hebrew.
This is my code and the result is that all file is converted to: "title":"\u05de\u05e1\u05d9...

Should i convert it? i want it to be readable

```
$additionalArray = array(
    'id' => 1,
    'title' => 'כותרת',
    'author' => 'תוכן'
  );

//open or read json data
$data_results = file_get_contents('../db/memory.json');
$tempArray = json_decode($data_results, true);

//append additional json to json file
$tempArray[] = $additionalArray ;
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);

file_put_contents('../db/memory.json', $jsonData);
```

Comment: You should not care how the data looks like in the JSON file. Read the data from file, decode it as before (using `json_decode()`) and check (print) the values. If they are correct (and they are) then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second parameter to json_encode is an options bitmask. You can supply JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to prevent PHP from escaping your strings.

```
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```